# Retrieve image of image control as byte array which is set using generichandler(.ashx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, generic-handler

currently I'm using `GenericHandler(.ashx)` for displaying an image in image control.

See below code:

```
[1] .ASPX
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="415px" />
[2] .cs(codebehind)
    Image1.ImageUrl = string.Format("GridviewImage.ashx?ItemID={0}", itemID);
```

Now I need to get image of `Image1` as a byte array (`byte[]`).

Is it possible?

Comment: I asked a similar question here (includes code):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507572/streaming-databased-images-using-httphandler

Comment: Thanks for suggestion........i have seen `public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }` ....but i don't know how to use it please post code snippet as answer thank you so much

Comment: How are you using a handler? All I see is a static image in the ASPX and I'm not sure what your question is? I'm posting a snippet that uses a handler to put an image in a GridView, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several images being streamed to the page, set the IsReusable to true. Use a DataReader for streaming the image back, not a DataSet like the other link.

```
<img src='ImageHandler.ashx?ProductID=<%# Eval("ProductID")%>' alt="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>" 
    title="<%# Eval("ProductName") %>" />

    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString["productID"] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string ProductID = context.Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(ProductID) > 0)
                    {
#if DEBUG
      const string CONN = "Initial Catalog=db1;Data Source=server1;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
#else
      const string CONN = "server=server2;database=db2;uid=un2;pwd=pw2;";
#endif
                        string selectQuery = "SELECT Photo FROM dbo.Products WHERE dbo.Products.ProductID=" + ProductID.ToString();
                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONN);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);

                        conn.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        dr.Read();
                        context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
                        dr.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                        // context.Response.End(); --> caused an "Abort thread" error - this is correct and is a special exception
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorReporting.LogError(ex);   
                }
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("No ProductID parameter specified");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry if this is foolish question because i am newbie to asp.net...here `context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);` is in `ImageHandler ` how could i retrieve from my codebehind(.cs) file...Thank you so much for answering

Comment: This code is a class and not your code-behind. The img tag at the top is in your ASPX form and makes an inline call to the handler class.

Comment: ok one more question...`ImageHandler ` will set image in `Image`  control of `.aspx` page. after that if i want to get `byte array(byte[])`  of Image which is now in `Image` control of `.aspx` page.....thank you so much

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The handler has streamed the image to the page and it displays. What else are you trying to do?

Comment: thank you so much...and sorry if i annoying you....but i want back the stream of image.  i want to stream the image of image control(`Image1` which is in .ASPX page).

Comment: You've already got the image via the handler, so if you need to do something else with that image just call the handler to serve it up.

Comment: how to call handler to retrieve image which was displayed by handler in image control(`Image1` which is in `.ASPX` page)....thank you so much for replying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17848/discussion-between-irishchieftain-and-pritesh)