# ASP.NET HTTP Handler for returning images from a database

Tags: asp.net

Assuming that I have already fetched a byte array from the database, how do I create a ASP.NET HTTP Handler that would return the image?

http://zombies.test/GetImage?id=10

Comment: when was the byte array retrieved, and where is it kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question here:

[Streaming Databased Images Using HttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507572/streaming-databased-images-using-httphandler)

**Important:** I ended up using a DataReader instead.