# Get images from database and show in grid view in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I have leafshape tableImage data table have image in image format

Getting data from table as

```
public DataSet GetLeafShape(string con)
{
        string query = "SELECT * FROM LeafShape";

        try
        {
            return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(con, CommandType.Text, query);               
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

I want to pass this data to gridview. How I can do it?

I try this but image is not showing. How to convert data to image?

```
GridViewleaf.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridViewleaf.DataBind();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to stream the images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507572/streaming-databased-images-using-httphandler

Comment: Since you are not doing anything with the exceptions, you can collapse them down into a single catch